# Where does this shloka about epidemic appear in Narada, Vashishtha or Vrahta Samhita?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, evidence

Where does this shloka about epidemic appear in Narada, Vashishtha or Vrahta Samhita?

> भूपाव हो महारोगो मध्य स्यार्धवृष्ट य। दुखिनो जंत्व सर्वे वत्स रे परी धाविनी

There are lot of videos and articles (for example, [this one](https://www.naidunia.com/chhattisgarh/raipur-prediction-of-epidemic-was-in-narada-samhita-10-thousand-years-ago-5430367) or [this video snapshot (3.48)](https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=606318773284101&id=268706653235574&sfnsn=wiwspwa&extid=0nNA4Nel6wY61GQC)) relating this Shloka with currently going on epidemic (Corona Virus / COVID-19).

Comment: There is no verse as such, may be some Sanskrit commentary on it may have. You can verify here: https://archive.org/details/naradasamhita

Answer (score 6):

I have just gone through Narada Samhita, Sanskrit text with Hindi translation book available on [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/naradasamhita) but I have **not found** the mentioned verse in it.

All the sites/articles citing this shloka are saying that (interpretation of the mentioned verse) "**In the Samvatsar called PariDhawi**, there will be war between the kings and an epidemic will spread. Rain will be unusual and all beings will be sad.

There are total 55 Adhayayas (chapters) in Narada Sanhita. 3rd chapter deals with Samvatsara. And here is a description of **Paridhavi Samvatsara** in verse 62 (which is quite different than what's claimed):

> [image]

Transliterating and Translating:

> anarghyāmayarogebhyo bhītirītirniraṃtaram ॥
>   **paridhāvī**vatsare tu nṛṇāṃ vṛṣṭistu madhyamā॥62॥
>
> In the year named Paridhavi, there be expensive food etc., continuous fear of diseases and moderate rain.

Here there is no mention of "महारोगो" or epidemic. Although diseases are mentioned in general but that is not a special case of Paridhavi Samvatsara, diseases are mentioned for few other Samvatsaras also.

Comment: I also got a video in WhatsApp group and in the video snapshot (3.48), the shloka is visible - https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=606318773284101&id=268706653235574&sfnsn=wiwspwa&extid=0nNA4Nel6wY61GQC

Comment: @Lakhi I see the book which was in his hand was "Vashishtha Sanhita"

Comment: can u pls provide references from Vashishtha Sanhita then?