# What Puranas and Shastras comment about the reason behind pandemics?

Tags: karma, sin

I am thinking if the Corona pandemic we are suffering is the result of similar and collective  bad Karma of almost all we people on earth. What Puranas and Shastras comment about the reason behind such pandemics?

Comment: Last line of Q description are suitable for title..ur current title looks opinion based..

Comment: Right bro! Thanks !

Comment: @Deepeshkumar: Dr. Paul Brunton, the author of **A search in Secret India** visited Egypt .  During one of his visits to pyramids, he had met an ascetic of great calibre, which he had mentioned in his another book **A search in Secret Egypt**.  The ascetic he met stated that some of the English researchers opened great pyramids in Egypt out of curiosity, in which many evil forces were kept arrested by the then sorcerers of Egypt.  Due to this act of Englishmen, those Evil forces came out and spread in the world.  He said the mankind will suffer by calamities in future due to those evil forces

Comment: Does [Where does this shloka about epidemic appear in Narada, Vashishtha or Vrahta Samhita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/38794/12304) answers your question?

Comment: Currently all have the same opionion what is the cure for pandemics? Nobody raised because it will be flagged off as opinion based. In srirangam temple almanac  this was mentioned--- In Jan 2020 disease will be spread. The almanac was printed in January 2019. But no remedy is mentioned. As deepesh said rightly that no one is genuine. All the humans are having atleast one bad quality. Ex.. Jealousy, thinking bad, abusing immediately,no fear of God etc. The main culprit is Cinema besides mega serials which yields nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Pandemics are part of the package deal for Samsara. Any one who chooses to live in Samsara will have to face tapatraya or three types of suffering.

**Three types of suffering**

> Of what avail will be the wealth and the objects of enjoyment gained
> by great effort for man who is naturally subject to the three types of
> sufferings caused by his own body and mind (**Adhyatmika**), **by external
> natural forces (Adhibhautika)**, and by extra-human agencies
> (**Adhidaivika**)?

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana VII.13.30**

Pandemics are classified to be Adhibhautika suffering or act of nature. They cannot be avoided.

God is generally not active in worldly affairs according to Hindu scripture. It is nature that does everything. The implication is that pandemics are due to nature. The reason for pandemics is nature.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. It’s about _the reason behind_ pandemics. It's asking, why? Not, what. Your blockquote simply lists the types of sufferings.

Comment: God is generally not active in worldly affairs according to Hindu scripture. It is nature that does everything. The implication is that pandemics are due to nature. The reason for pandemics is nature.