# Did our Rishis mention any of our future events in Puranas?

Tags: scripture, puranas, history, belief

I saw some social media posts that covid was mentioned in Puranas. Is this true? If yes, did our ancestors visualise our future?

My point of view to this question is, there is 10th incarnation of lord Vishnu as Kalki mentioned in Puranas. So, our Rishis saw the end of Kaliyug (which is our Future) must have crossed visualisation of our present.

Did any puranas mentioned about any important events like disasters in our Puranas like Bhavishya Purana or Bhagavata purana or in any other puranas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does this shloka about epidemic appear in Narada, Vashishtha or Vrahta Samhita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38794/where-does-this-shloka-about-epidemic-appear-in-narada-vashishtha-or-vrahta-sam)

Comment: Thank you for hour comment. But looks like this is not what I am looking at.